# one to one and one to many relation with same entity mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, one-to-many, entity-relationship

I have two entities **Invoice** and **User**. 
Invoice have following relations with user

1. invoice have a owner(**one to one** relation with user)
2. one invoice can share with multiple users, it means invoice can have multiple shared  users(**one to many** relation with user)

How to map these relations in mysql database? how many tables? and table structure?

Answer (score 0):

invoice could have two fields, billed_to and payed_by. your billed_to field would be your one to one relationship, and the payed_by field would be your one to many.

Answer (score 0):

For One-to-one relationship, it is advised not to keep separate table. Keep it with the invoice table itself.

For one-to-many relationship, keep another mapping table.

Your table structure should be

```
Users
----------
id  | xxx | .....
```

-

```
Invoices
------------
id  | user_id | .....
```

in the above case user_id is the owner.

```
shared_invoices
-------------------
id | user_id | invoice_id
```